# How to use third party js in rails 6 using webpack?

Tags: rubygems, webpack-4, ruby-2.7, ruby-on-rails-6

using ruby 2.7.1p83 and Rails 6.0.3.2 in rails project.

imported huebee inside the rails appliction webpack.

```
 yarn add huebee
```

imported its css and js files for the in the application.js and application.css files respectively:

```
for application.js
import 'huebee/huebee';
for application.css
@import "~huebee/huebee";
```

Now, if

```
 <input class="color-input" data-huebee='{ "notation": "hex", "saturations": 2 }'/>
```

[image]

is working fine and showing the drow box for colour selector:

but when I initialise the Huebee object inside js it given error as:

```
var hueb = new Huebee('.color-sample', {
    notation: 'hex',
    saturations: 2,
    staticOpen: true,
    hues: 6,

});
```

[image]
[image]

Uncaught ReferenceError: Huebee is not defined

please suggest the right approach to fix this issue thanks in advance.

my user.js file where Huebee is imported as:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
import "popper.js";
import "bootstrap";
import 'owl.carousel';
import 'jquery.easing';
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import '../stylesheets/user.scss';
import Huebee from 'huebee/huebee';
require.context('../images', true, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/);
```

user.scss file:

```
@import '~bootstrap';
@import '~owl.carousel2/dist/assets/owl.theme.default';
@import '~owl.carousel2/dist/assets/owl.carousel';
@import "~huebee/huebee";
```

Huebee script for initialisation:

```
(function () {
    const element= document.querySelector('.color-sample');
    var hueb = new Huebee(element, {
        notation: 'hex',
        saturations: 2,
        staticOpen: true,
        hues: 6,
    });
})();
```

This gives following error:
[image]

Comment: In which JS file have you initialised the Huebee. If you are using the file other than application js. Then you need to attack Huebee class to global variable or window to access in other js files.

Comment: I have imported 'huebee/huebee' inside application.js file and initialize Hubee in the same file.

Comment: Can you edit your question with full code of application.js

Comment: Updated the answer with user.js and user.scss file becuase application.js and application.scss file are update to some thing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `Huebee` class from the package.

In application.js

```
import Huebee from 'huebee/huebee';
```

In your js code, pass element as reference instead of directly passing .color-sample. And make sure the following code runs after document load.

```
const element= document.querySelector('.color-input');
var hueb = new Huebee(element, {
    notation: 'hex',
    saturations: 2,
    staticOpen: true,
    hues: 6,
});
```

Comment: 30:210 Uncaught ReferenceError: Huebee is not defined still same issue.

Comment: @vidurpunj  I have replicated and it's working fine. Can you edit your question with complete code, so that we can understand the exact issue

Comment: Updated the answer with user.js and user.scss file becuase application.js and application.scss file are update to some thing else.

Comment: @vidurpunj where is Huebee initialisation? In which js

Comment: @vidurpunj is the initialisation in user.js? If not try moving to the user.js or declare it as window or global variable to make it accessible

Comment: global.Huebee = Huebee; add this in user.js if you are using in external js

Comment: this initialisation is done at the detals.html.erb page which is having the user.html.erb as it layout.

Comment: It's a bad approach to write scripts in erb files. I suggest you to move it to custom js file and include it to user.js or if you declare Huebee as global as suggested above to use it in erb file

Comment: huebee.js:33 Uncaught Error: Bad element for Huebee: null , error message is changed now.

Comment: @vidurpunj Huebee is initialised, but element is not getting referenced, I hope it is in the document ready

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219935/discussion-between-vidur-punj-and-ravi-teja-gadi).

Answer (score 0):

user.js file:

```
import Huebee from 'huebee/huebee';
global.Huebee = Huebee;
```

The erb file which is using Huebee is as:

```
  <input class="color-input" data-huebee='{ "notation": "hex", "saturations": 2 }'/>

(function () {
    const element= document.querySelector('.color-input');
    var hueb = new Huebee(element, {
        notation: 'hex',
        saturations: 2,
        staticOpen: true,
        hues: 6,
    });
})();
```